# jQuery on data-xxxx modified event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way of catching the modification of a specific data attribute (i.e. 'data-whatever')? My first thought was to go with DOM mutation observer but was wondering if there's any 'easier' way through jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

> if there's any 'easier' way through jQuery?

There is no attribute change event.

Be careful with those "DOM mutation" events, they are deprecated and not supported in all browsers as much as I know.

Better solution is: When you toggle the data.* attribute call that function you want.

Comment: FYI: I just found out about $(selector).bind('getData.xxxx', ....) and 'setData respectively at http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#11
It's getting late here (working Monday morning) so will probably pursue this from work as well ;)
Should anyone has a working knowledge of the mentioned methodology please enlighten us ;)
Cheers

Comment: @Virus. Let me know if you found something interesting. though I really think that last solution is your winner.